# PHP - Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct(): Argument #1 ($store) must be of type Dotenv\Store\StoreInterface, string given

Tags: php, environment-variables

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct(): Argument #1 ($store) must be of type Dotenv\Store\StoreInterface, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\app\config_env.php on line 7 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Dotenv.php:60 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\app\config_env.php(7): Dotenv\Dotenv->__construct('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\public\index.php(3): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Dotenv.php on line 60

I am geting this error when trying to "echo" APP_NAME in ".env" file. I am using "vlucas/phpdotenv 5.5" and app works fine with "vlucas/phpdotenv 2.4"

**index.php**
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\public

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/config/_env.php';

$app_name = getenv('APP_NAME');

echo $app_name;
```

**.env**
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I
APP_ENV=local

APP_NAME="ACME E-commerce Store"

#database

DB_DRIVER='mysql'

DB_HOST=localhost

DB_NAME=store

DB_USERNAME=store

DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**_env**
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\app\config

```
<?php

define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../'));

require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotEnv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(BASE_PATH);

$dotEnv->load();
```

**Dotenv.php**
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src

```
  line 60 -> public function __construct(
        StoreInterface $store,
        ParserInterface $parser,
        LoaderInterface $loader,
        RepositoryInterface $repository
    ) {
        $this->store = $store;
        $this->parser = $parser;
        $this->loader = $loader;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
```

I tried following changes in
**_env**
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTheCompletePHPMVCourse_I\app\config

```
$dotEnv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(BASE_PATH);

$dotEnv->safeLoad();
```

got no errors but nothing comes up

Comment: According to the code on [github](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/1a7ea2afc49c3ee6d87061f5a233e3a035d0eae7/src/Dotenv.php#L148)  your last approach is better. On the other hand it seems that something wrong with the pass to the `.env` file. Instead of `__DIR__.'/../../'` try simply `__DIR__`. But ideally i would run script through XDEBUG in order to see what values you are getting on the runtime.

Comment: I tried `__DIR__` it create more Errors @SergeyLigus

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/master/UPGRADING.md), I tried this:

```
(Dotenv\Dotenv::create(
Dotenv\Repository\RepositoryBuilder::createWithDefaultAdapters()->make(), BASE_PATH)
)->load();
```

Comment: "*I tried this*" - Is this an answer, a comment or a question?

Comment: not a very sure answer @DarkBee

Comment: Well does this snippet work?